# Launch call from widget in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-intent, widget, phone-call

Is it possible to lauch a call by pressing a button within a home screen widget in android?

I have the following code and it does not work, pressing the button does nothing:

```
public class WidgetTestActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {

        @Override
        public void onEnabled(Context context)
        {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

            String url = "tel:3334444";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            PendingIntent call1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, call1);   
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The AppWidgetProvider has the method `onRecive(Context context, Intent intent)` in wich you can check the intent action and execute the code you want.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_CALL))
    {
        //DO WHAT YOU WANT
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is the Intent to be launched is already specified with Intent.ACTION_CALL, i.e. when used in a real Activity  the call is Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.CALL_ACTION);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:69342"));
   startActivity(intent);

Comment: you can even define an Action by yourself (it is just a string). if so you have to register the AndroidManifest.xml that the AppWidgetProvider you are defining will consume that particular Intent Action.
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(..); by this metohd you set that when the button will be clicked an intent as the specified will be fired and you can put your code in the onRecive Checking the Intent Action...
i don't kno if this was waht you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Did you specified the CALL_PHONE permission in the Android Manifest?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE

Comment: I have that permission defined, yes.